# Struct With Fixed Sized Array Of Another Struct

Tags: c#, arrays, winapi, struct

How do you declare a struct in C# with a fixed sized array of another struct ? I need [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183375%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) declared so that it works. Or is my approach wrong if I want the bitmapinfo (-header) created ?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RGBQUAD
{
    public byte b;
    public byte g;
    public byte r;
    public byte reserved;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct BITMAPINFO
{
    public BITMAPINFOHEADER bmiHeader;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStruct, SizeConst = 1)]
    public RGBQUAD[] bmiColors;
}
```

**Edit:** What I learned myself is that `UnmanagedType.ByValArray` and `SizeConst = 1` is important here to keep the [BITMAPINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183375%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) marshal size constantly at 44 bytes event if I assign 256 sized array of RGBQUAD.

**Edit 2:** But SizeConst mustn't be smaller than the actual array size otherwise unmanaged code can crash the app.

Comment: You can't declare a fixed-size struct, you can only declare how a struct gets marshalled during interop.

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/BITMAPINFOHEADER.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments, in C# you can't create a fixed size array of structs in a struct.

But that's not what you want.  In the declaration

```
typedef struct tagBITMAPINFO {
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmiHeader;
    RGBQUAD          bmiColors[1];
} BITMAPINFO, *PBITMAPINFO;
```

`bmiColors` is declared as a fixed-length array but it is really a place holder for a variable length array of `RGBQUAD`.  The actual length of the array depends ([in a slightly complicated way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd183376%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) on the value of `bmiHeader.biClrUsed`.

How you handle this in C# depends entirely on what you are doing with the `BITMAPINFO` structure.

**Update**

I've just seen your other question.  You're passing the `BITMAPINFO` to `SetDIBits` and your colour table always has 256 entries.  So in the declaration of `BITMAPINFO.bmiColors` set `SizeConst` to 256.

Comment: I need a reusable solution for any palette size. So I would like to keep the size original at 1. Does this mean my declaration here is correct ?

Comment: When you marshal a structure from .Net into a native API the data is actually copied.  If you set SizeConst to 1, then only one entry of your palette will be copied.  At best, your image colours will be wrong.  At worst, SetDIBits will crash when it reads past the end of the allocated buffer.  If you set it to 256 you don't have to use all the entries.

Comment: Yes, this fixes the crash at least at CreatePalette. Can I make Marshal copy dynamically in case I don't have 256 colors but 16 or 8 ?

Comment: Structs don't have a dynamic length, so the marshaller doesn't support this as a built-in option.  You can always write your own marshalling code (using the methods in the Marshal class) but doing this on each call to SetDIBits might be slower than using the built-in support.  Copying 256 RGBQUADs doesn't take a long time.

Comment: But you could make it faster.  Presumably the information passed in BITMAPINFO (i.e. bitmap dimensions and palette) don't change between calls.  So you could marshal the structure once into unmanaged memory and use this every time you call SetDIBits.  But I really wouldn't bother making any changes until you'd profiled your code and determined that the overhead of marshalling BITMAPINFO was actually significant.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately (and IMHO somewhat surprisingly given that one of the design objectives of .net was to facilitate interop with COM) the .net runtime has no understanding of any kind of array other than standalone `System.Array` objects or the character arrays built into `System.String`.  Although C# offers `fixed` array types, those are manipulated using pointer arithmetic in a way that the .net runtime doesn't really understand and cannot validate.

It is possible to create something that behaves like a fixed-sized array by defining a struct with elements `a0`, `a1`, `a2`, etc. and writing an indexed property which uses a switch statement or other such construct to access elements thereof, but such constructs are likely to perform much slower than normal arrays.

If you don't need to use `safe` code (and given the fact that you're interoperating with what's probably untrusted managed code, "safe" code probably isn't a consideration) I'd suggest that you define your `RGBQUAD` using explicit layout, to overlap an `int` with your other data, and then having your other structure include a `fixed int[whateverSize];` to hold the RGB data.  Its indexed accessor should be able to convert `int` to `RGBQUAD` rather efficiently by just reading/writing its "int" member.